# django render и redirect

Tags: django

Функция render принимает словарь переменных для шаблона.
Может ли redirect принимать переменные что бы работать с ними в другой вьюхе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `redirect` вы можете указывать только параметры для построения URL.

Например:

```
# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import Articles_List, Article

urlpatterns = [
    path('', Articles_List.as_view(), name='article-list'),
    path('<int:id>/', Article.as_view(), name='article'),
]
```

Тогда в во views.py вам будет необходимо указывать:

```
return redirect('article-list') # для первой ссылки роута
return redirect('article', id=<id вашей статьи>) # для второй ссылки роута
```

*Поэтому если коротко отвечать на ваш вопрос: нет, не может.*

Comment: Тогда можно ли через рендер перейти на другую вьюху и передать значения?

Comment: Вы можете просто написать условие и рендерить нужный вам шаблон, передавая в него данные. Или, если пользуютесь классами и знаете ООП, расширять свои классы другими и возвращать нужные вам данные в нужный шаблон.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы что-то делаете не так, потому как `redirect` может принимать только URL, на который и будет перенаправление.
Если вам нужно передать какие-то данные "между вьюхами", используйте `request.session`, базу данных, cookies и т.п.